# Synthesising FOR-GENERATE in VHDL

Tags: for-loop, vhdl, synthesis

I am using FOR-GENERATE  and IF-GENERATE in VHDL program.Is these commands are synthesizable?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of these commands.
Can we use FOR-GENERATE inside IF-GENERATE?
Because when I am using FOR-GENERATE inside IF-GENERATE then it is creating an error

Comment: Generate statements certainly are synthesizable, also any combination of them. A very common error when doing for-generate statements is related to handling the signals inside the statement. Post your Code and we'll see...

Answer (score 1):

*Is these commands are synthesizable?*
Yes, they're synthesizable if you use them correctly.

*advantages and disadvantages of these commands*
For advantages, GENERATE statement makes it easy to create wellpatterned structures. For disadvantages, see @BennyBarns's comment below.

*Can we use FOR-GENERATE inside IF-GENERATE?*
Any VHDL concurrent statement can be included in a GENERATE statement, including another GENERATE statement.

---

[[LRM93](http://edg.uchicago.edu/~tang/VHDLref.pdf) $9.7]

> generation_scheme ::=
>   for generate_parameter_speciﬁcation
>   | if condition

**With the FOR scheme**
1.All objects created are similar.
2.Loop cannot be terminated early.

**With the IF scheme**
1.Allows for conditional creation of components.
2.Can’t use ELSE or ELSIF clauses.

Comment: The Generate Statement itself doesn't cost anything. Only the code you are instancing (maybe repeatedly in case of a for-generate-statement) uses resources of course.